# Check for a build up name if it exist in a list of names -python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I'm trying to build a cvs file that has all Active directory fields I need, from 2 external files. 
the first file has a list of users that need to be created and some other info relevant to an AD object

and the second report is a list of exported  SamAccountName and emails dumped from AD. So what I want to do is create a unique SamAccountName, I form my test SamaAccountName from the firstname and lastname of the first report and wan to compare it vs the second report. I'm currently storing ins alist all the data I get from the second report  and I want to check my generated SamAccountName exists in that list

so far I'm not able to do so and only get a csv with the SamAccoutnNames I made up( it does not do the check )

note: I can't use any other plugin to check directly to Active Directory

```
import csv

def getSamA(fname, lname):
    Sams = []
    sama = lname[0:5] + fname[0:2]

    with open('test-input.txt','r') as AD:
        rows = csv.DictReader(AD)

        for ad in rows:
            Sams.append(ad['SamAccountName'])


    #check if built sama is in list       
    if sama in Sams:

        #if sama in list, add one more character to sama
        sama = lname[0:5] + fname[0:3]
        return sama.lower()
    else:
        return sama.lower()

with open('users.csv') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('users-COI2-Multi.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        header = ['FirstName','Initials','LastName','DisplayName','Description','Office','TelePhone','UserLogonName','SamAccountName','JobTitle','Department','Manager','Mobile','faxNumber','Notes','Assistant','employeeID','ex1','ex2','ex3','ex15','Office365License','ExpiresInDays','EmailToUSer','AddToGroup']

        output_file = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=header, delimiter=';')
        output_file.writeheader()

        for data in rows:
            employeeId = data['Associate ID']
            fName = data['First Name']
            lName = data['Last Name']
            Location = data['Location']
            Department = data['Department']
            Manager = data['Manager Name']
            JobTitle = data['Title']

            context = {
                'FirstName' : fName,
                'Initials' : getInitials(fName, lName),
                'LastName' : lName,
                'DisplayName' : getDisplayName(fName, lName),
                'Description' : 'Account for: '+getDisplayName(fName, lName),
                'Office': getOffice(Location).strip(),
                'TelePhone' : '+1 XXX XXX XXXX',
                'UserLogonName' : getMail(fName, lName),
                'SamAccountName' : getSamA(fName, lName),
                'JobTitle' : JobTitle,
                'Department' : Department,
                'Manager' : Manager,
                'Mobile' : '',
                'faxNumber' : '',
                'Notes' : '',
                'Assistant' : '',
                'employeeID' : employeeId,
                'ex1' : 'End User',
                'ex2' : 'NoMailbox',
                'ex3' : getSiteCode(Location),
                'ex15' : getSKID(Location),
                'Office365License' : '',
                'ExpiresInDays' : '',
                'EmailToUSer' : 'user@test.com',
                'AddToGroup' : '',
            }
            output_file.writerow(context)
```

Comment: Which part specifically isn't working?

Comment: the check attempt  for uniqueness in the **getSamA()**  function, I want to make a check if the sama i built is in the list  Sams and it does not work ,, i do get the final csv but with the SamAccountName i created  unchecked